# How to disallow all bots from indexing a website except googlebot or/and other specific bot?

Tags: .htaccess

I am very bad at .htaccess, so i would like to ask you the following question.
I would like my website to be indexed only by googlebot.How can I disallow all the other robots?I am asking to disallow bots using .htaccess file ,not robots.txt.

Comment: I think this has been answered before here..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805831/will-this-robots-txt-only-allow-googlebot-to-index-my-site

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Though, I am asking whether you can block agents using .htaccess not robots.txt.